# Produce new panda dataframe from old, by keeping the minimum across subsets of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form

```
data = [{'Energy': 2,'spin': 1},{'Energy': 6,'spin': 2},{'Energy':5,'spin':2},
        {'Energy': 15,'spin': 5},{'Energy': 4,'spin': 1},  {'Energy': 10,'spin': 5}]

df=pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Particle 1', 'Particle 2','Particle 3',
                             'Particle 4','Particle 5','Particle 6'])
print(df)
```

For each group of particles **with the same spin**, I'd like to keep only the one with minimum energy and drop the rest. This is, the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
dataclean = [{'Energy': 2,'spin': 1},{'Energy': 5,'spin': 2},{'Energy': 10,'spin': 5}]

df2=pd.DataFrame(dataclean, index=['Particle 1','Particle 3','Particle 6'])
print(df2)

            Energy  spin
Particle 1       2     1
Particle 3       5     2
Particle 6      10     5
```

I've tried different approaches unsuccessfully. What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `idxmin()` to find out the index where the *Energy* is minimum for each *spin*, then use it to subset the original data frame (this assume you don't have duplicated index):

```
df.loc[df.groupby("spin").Energy.idxmin()]
```

[image]

---

*Another option*: use `nsmallest`

```
df.groupby('spin').Energy.nsmallest(1).reset_index(level=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works nicely! Update: What if I have two particles with the exact same spin and the exact same energy (say the minimum for that spin). For example, say I have a 'Particle 7' with Energy= 10 and spin = 5 (i.e. the same as 'Particle 6').  Is it possible to keep both 'Particle 6' and 'Particle 7' in the new dataframe?

Comment: In that case, you want to keep equal minimums, you can use `groupby.transform` to calculate a equal length minimum vector and use it for subsetting. `df[df.Energy == df.groupby('spin').Energy.transform('min')]`

Comment: Works great, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Source DF

```
In [70]: df
Out[70]:
            Energy  spin
Particle 1       2     1
Particle 2       6     2
Particle 3       5     2
Particle 4      15     5
Particle 5       4     1
Particle 6      10     5
Particle 7      10     5   # i've added this row
```

Solution, that uses [GroupBy.rank(method='dense')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html) method

```
In [71]: df.loc[df.groupby('spin').Energy.rank(method='dense').le(1)]
Out[71]:
            Energy  spin
Particle 1       2     1
Particle 3       5     2
Particle 6      10     5
Particle 7      10     5
```

Explanation:

```
In [72]: df.groupby('spin').Energy.rank(method='dense')
Out[72]:
Particle 1    1.0
Particle 2    2.0
Particle 3    1.0
Particle 4    2.0
Particle 5    2.0
Particle 6    1.0
Particle 7    1.0
Name: Energy, dtype: float64

In [73]: df.groupby('spin').Energy.rank(method='dense').le(1)
Out[73]:
Particle 1     True
Particle 2    False
Particle 3     True
Particle 4    False
Particle 5    False
Particle 6     True
Particle 7     True
Name: Energy, dtype: bool
```

---

**OLD answer:**

Alternative solution:

```
In [60]: df.sort_values('Energy').groupby('spin').head(1)
Out[60]:
            Energy  spin
Particle 1       2     1
Particle 3       5     2
Particle 6      10     5
```

PS please be aware that [@Psidom's solution: `df.groupby('spin').Energy.nsmallest(1).reset_index(level=0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42731088/5741205) is more idiomatic and should perform much better

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's great to have multiple solutions

Comment: @Jon, you are welcome. I've added another solution, which should take care of duplicates